# Change number of columns in grid

Tags: grid-layouts, column

I'm looking to make a grid where the number of columns change, but the grid spacings remain roughly the same. Essentially, something like SpanFromLeft, but applied to an entire row rather than a single cell. The closest thing I've been able to get is a nested grid, but this has an unwanted padding on it that I can't figure out how to get rid of.

```
Grid[{{a,b,c,d},{e,f,g,h},{Grid[{{i,j,k},{l,m,n}},Frame->All],SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft}},Frame->All]
```

Results in:

[image: result]

But I'm looking to remove the empty space around {{i,j,k},{l,m,n}} and widen the bottom rows cells to match the upper rows total width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** a more flexible approach:

```
griD = {Grid[{#}, Dividers -> {Center, None}, 
     Alignment -> {Center, Center},
     ItemSize -> {Scaled[1/Length[#]], 2}]} &;

data = {{a, b, c, d, 1}, {e, f, g, h, 1}, {i, j, k}, {l, m, n},
   {s, t}, {1000}, Range[7]};

Grid[griD /@ data, 
 ItemSize -> {20, 2}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = TakeList[Range @ Total @ #, #] & @ RandomChoice[Range[12], 20];
data = Map[Item[#, Background -> Opacity[.3, RandomColor[]]] &, data, {-1}];

Grid[griD /@ data, ItemSize -> {40, 2}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
w1 = 3;
w2 = 4;
h1 = 3;

Grid[{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g,  h},
  {Grid[{{i, j, k}, {l, m, n}}, Dividers -> Center, ItemSize -> {w2, h1}, 
    Spacings -> {0, 0}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}],  SpanFromLeft}}, 
 ItemSize -> {w1, h1}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

With

```
w1 = 5;
w2 = (4/3) w1;
```

we get

[image]

and with

```
w1 = {6, 5, 5, 6};
w2 = {6, 10, 6};
h1 = 2;
```

[image]